# I'm using PowerBuilder and have a problem with the ( if, or, and ) condition

Tags: powerbuilder

what i want if i choosed one of checbox but i don't inputed the text or 'c_ao', then messagebox is displaying

i have tried edit the query, like edit symbol "()" position

if Not IsNull(f_na) or Not IsNull(f_dep) or Not IsNull(f_krd) and IsNull (c_ao) then
    messagebox ('Warning','need fill in C_AO')
    return
end if

i have
3 checkbox ('f_na','f_dep','f_krd')
1 input text/singelineedit ('c_ao')

my expectation is if i choosed some of checkbox in datawindow, and i don't inputed the input text/singelineedit or 'c_ao' then then messagebox ('Warning','need fill in C_AO') is displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first part of your logic is for any of the three checkboxes to be checked you would do this:

```
IF (f_na.checked OR f_dep.checked OR f_krd.checked) AND ISNULL (c_ao.text) THEN
   Messagebox(blah, blah)
END IF
```

This looks to see if any of the checkboxes have been checked and if so, is there text in the singlelineedit control.